# How to download an image when working in inappbrowser of cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have made a hybrid android app using cordova documentation of inappbrowser but when I open google images and want to download an image I can't. There is no context menu popping up on long press on image.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution by now?